# Cannot add lambda layer via GUI or programmatically, but works via cloud formation. Failed to unzip archive: Zip file contains invalid files/folders;

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-lambda-layers

I'm following this excellent article: https://github.com/vittorio-nardone/selenium-chromium-lambda/

End to end the example works correctly - I just want to re-use the layers that are created in my own function.

Whatever method I use to try and add the layer fails. Manually using GUI,Boto3 in python or the AWS CLI, although it is working on the function setup up by the cloud formation script.

```
aws lambda update-function-configuration --function-name='test_headless' --layers='arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-1:366134052888:layer:SeleniumChromiumLayer:1'

An error occurred (InvalidParameterValueException) when calling the UpdateFunctionConfiguration operation: Failed to unzip archive: Zip file contains invalid files/folders;
```

Clearly I'm missing something here:

Partial Extract from cloud formation script:

```
    ScreenshotFunction:
        Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
        Properties:
            Runtime: python3.7
            Description: Function to take a screenshot of a website.
            Handler: src/lambda_function.lambda_handler
            Role: 
                Fn::GetAtt: [ "ScreenshotFunctionRole", "Arn" ]
            Environment:
                Variables:
                    PYTHONPATH: "/var/task/src:/opt/python"
                    PATH: "/opt/bin:/opt/bin/lib"
                    URL: 
                        Ref: WebSite
                    BUCKET:
                        Ref: BucketName
                    DESTPATH:
                        Ref: ScreenshotsFolder
            Timeout: 60
            MemorySize: 2048
            Code:
                S3Bucket: 
                    Ref: BucketName
                S3Key: 
                    Fn::Sub: '${SourceFolder}/ScreenshotFunction.zip'
            Layers:
                - Ref: SeleniumChromiumLayer

    SeleniumChromiumLayer:
        Type: AWS::Lambda::LayerVersion
        Properties:
            CompatibleRuntimes:
                - python3.7
                - python3.6
            Content:
                S3Bucket: 
                    Ref: BucketName
                S3Key: 
                    Fn::Sub: '${SourceFolder}/SeleniumChromiumLayer.zip'
            Description: Selenium and Chromium Layer for Python3.6
```

How is it that the contents of the zip used can be OK to add via cloudformation but not in any other manner?

Answer (score 0):

Seems there was some corruption on a function - add the layer to another function worked successfully